# Lorentz Transformations and Angular Momentum unclear derivation

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

How do we get rid of $\omega^{\rho}_{\;\;\nu}$ and howt do we derive the last equation form the previous one. Here is URL for the source where I found this text [page 17 (marked at bottom)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of transformation, the infinitesimal parameter can be a scalar, vector, tensor etc.
We parameterize the change in the field as

1. Scalar: $\delta \phi = \alpha \Delta \phi$
2. Vector: $\delta \phi = \alpha^{\rho} (\Delta \phi)_{\rho}$
3. Tensor: $\delta \phi = \alpha^{\rho\sigma} (\Delta \phi)_{\rho\sigma}$

Correspondingly, more number of indices are involved in $F^{\mu}$ appearing in the change of Lagrangian. For example: (for the above three cases)

1. $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}+\alpha \partial_{\mu}F^{\mu}$
2. $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}+\alpha^{\rho} \partial_{\mu}\big((F^{\mu})_{\rho}\big)$
3. $\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}+\alpha^{\rho\sigma} \partial_{\mu}\big((F^{\mu})_{\nu\sigma}\big)$

This simply means that the current defined in eq.(1.38) in your reference (https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) will be $\mathcal{J}^{\mu}$, $(\mathcal{J}^{\mu})^{\rho}$ and $(\mathcal{J}^{\mu})^{\rho\sigma}$, respectively. It is written as:

1.$\big(\mathcal{J}^{\mu}\big)=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L})}\Delta \phi-(F^{\mu})$

2.$\big(\mathcal{J}^{\mu}\big)_{\rho}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L})}(\Delta \phi)_{\rho}-(F^{\mu})_{\rho}$

3.$\big(\mathcal{J}^{\mu}\big)_{\rho\sigma}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\mathcal{L})}(\Delta \phi)_{\rho\sigma}-(F^{\mu})_{\rho\sigma}$

Since the question is about a tensor case, let's focus on the item 3 above.

To read off $(F^{\mu}){\rho\sigma}$, the key point is to rewrite equation (1.53) as following
$$\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}-\omega^{\rho \sigma}\partial_{\mu}\big(\delta_{\rho}^{\mu} \delta_{\sigma \nu} x^{\nu} \mathcal{L}\big)=\mathcal{L}-\big(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\omega^{\rho \sigma}}_{\alpha_{\mu\nu}}\big)\partial_{\mu}\big(\underbrace{\delta_{\rho}^{\mu} \delta_{\sigma \nu} x^{\nu} \mathcal{L}-\delta_{\sigma}^{\mu} \delta_{\rho \nu} x^{\nu} \mathcal{L}}_{\big(F^{\mu}\big)_{\rho\sigma}}\big)$$
where we have used the fact that $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ is anti-symmetric.
Note also that $(\Delta\phi)_{\rho\sigma}$ only contributes by its anti-symmetric part. According to equation (1.52)
$$\delta \phi=-\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\omega^{\rho\sigma}}_{\alpha^{\rho \sigma}}\big(\underbrace{x_{\rho}\partial_{\sigma}\phi-x_{\sigma}\partial_{\rho}\phi}_{(\Delta\phi)_{\rho \sigma}}\big) $$
By the last two equations above you can compute $\big(\mathcal{J}^{\mu}\big)_{\rho\sigma}$  which turns out to be the same as (1.55).

Hope this helps.

P.S. The above discussion is based on Peskin-Schroeder section (2.2).

Comment: Thanks for answer, BUT I still don't understand how do we get the second term in equation (1.55)

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner I edited the answer to include your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one last small question, why did we get factor 1/2 and in the provided text there isn't one. Why does our result differ from the one provided? Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHenryBrenner I made a small change; now it gives exactly (1.55).